# Clicking on a radio button explicitly coded to close all bootstrap accordions opens them all instead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Open this up and on your first click, click on the "Third Radio with no Accordion"

http://jsfiddle.net/3F6TY/3/

Why does this reveal all the accordions, and only on the first click? My code explicitly tells it to **close** all accordions. No where did I instruct it to open anything...

```
          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="firstRadio" value="">
              First Radio
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 panel-collapse collapse" id="firstAccordion">
            <div>
              First Accordion
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="secondRadio">
              Second Radio
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 panel-collapse collapse" id="secondAccordion">
            <div>
              Second Accordion
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="radio col-xs-12">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="radios" class="track-order-change" id="thirdRadio">
              Third Radio with no Accordion
            </label>
          </div>

$('input[name="radios"]').change( function() {

    if ($('#firstRadio').is(":checked")){

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('show');

    } else {

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('hide');
    }

    if ($('#secondRadio').is(":checked")){

        $('#secondAccordion').collapse('show');

    } else {

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('hide');
    }

    if ($('#thirdRadio').is(":checked")){

        $('#firstAccordion').collapse('hide');
        $('#secondAccordion').collapse('hide');
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you put in an alert to make sure that your `$('#firstRadio').is(":checked")` is evaluating to what you think?

Comment: Yeah, `$('#firstRadio').is(":checked")` as well as `#secondRadio` returns false on the first time that I click the third radio button

Comment: in fact this code `$('#secondAccordion').collapse('hide');` shows your `#secondAccordion`, so weird indeed. I doubt that it's actually a bug. There is no reason it could show the div, if the div is collapsed, it should do nothing, if we want to toggle it, we already have `.collapse('toggle')`.

Comment: @KingKing, checking the third radio doesn't just show the second accordion, it also shows the first accordion as well. It is explicitly coded to *hide* them (not `toggle`, as you said), when checked. This issue is confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny I talked about `#secondAccordion` just as an example, generally speaking, `$('whateverhere').collapse('hide')` will show the element ***initially***. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/3F6TY/4/ , you can see how weird it is. It's surely a bug, terrible indeed.

Comment: @KingKing, so this is default behavior and there's no way to get around this?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny I don't think it's the default behavior, I also just don't understand why it's so. So I doubt it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.collapse('hide')` shoud not show the element ***in any context***, that is no matter the element is currently collapsed or expanded. You can compare this to how `.hide()` and `.show()` methods in jQuery works, no matter the current state of the element is visible or hidden, using `.hide()` should ensure that the element is hidden.

I've just found a way to work-around this bug-like issue. Firstly you need to add the class `in` intially for your accordions. Then call the `.collapse('hide')` initially to collapse the accordions (instead of using just the class `collapse` in HTML code):

**HTML**:

```
<!-- add the class "in" and also do this for all other accordions -->
<div class="col-xs-12 panel-collapse collapse in" id="firstAccordion">
     <div>
         First Accordion
     </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
//Just add this line to intially collapse the accordions
$('#firstAccordion, #secondAccordion').collapse('hide');
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3F6TY/5/)

Comment: Thanks. Right on load the open accordions all flash shut for a split second, but at least it works after that.